# Query com PagedList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Estou usando o PagedList.Mvc para paginação de resultados.

Mas ao fazer a seguinte action com as querys:

```
   public ActionResult Index(int? page, string searchString)
    {
        int pageSize = 10;
        int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
        var query = db.Grupos.AsQueryable();

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchString))
        {
            searchString = searchString.ToUpper();
            query = query.Where(x => x.Nome.ToUpper().Contains(searchString));
        }
        query = query.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id);

        query = query.Select(x => new Grupo
        {
            Id = x.Id,
            Nome = x.Nome
        });
        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            return PartialView("Lista", query.ToPagedList(pageNumber,pageSize));
        }
        return View(query.ToPagedList(pageNumber,pageSize));
    }
```

me deparo com o seguinte erro quando vai executar query.ToPagedList(pageNumber,pageSize):

```
Additional information: The entity or complex type 'Projeto.Entity.Grupo' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.
```

Gostaria que minha query buscasse apenas o Id e o Nome desse grupo

Comment: Você faz isso em uma `action` certo ? Se sim, coloque o `pagedlist` no `return` junto com o objeto... Tipo: `query.ToPagedList(1, 10);` e vê se funciona. Eu acho que é isso.

Comment: @ÉrikThiago Editei minha pergunta, é dessa forma que estou fazendo, e ainda obtendo o erro =(

Comment: Será que é porque você está usando duas vezes o `x` ali em suas expressões ? Tenta mudar a letra pra ver se funciona. Não sei, mas você está usando muitas vezes a `query`, pode ser que está dando conflito.

Comment: Não é por usar "x" não...se eu remover o "Select(x= >new .. ele funciona corretamente...

Comment: Entendi. Será que usando a cláusula `Where` não resolveria seu problema ? Estranho, me parece tão simples a sua expressão... Eu faço assim quando quero buscar somente dois dados:`Aluno aluno = db.Alunos.Include(x => .Ocorrencias)       .AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(f => f.AlunoID == id);`. E ai faz a ordenção da forma que você faz ai. Se achar que é válido adaptar ao seu cenário.

Comment: da forma que você faz você busca todas as propriedades da sua classe, digamos, eu tenho uma classe com 10 propriedades, Id, nome, etc, etc, eu quero pegar só o Id e fazer a query, no banco de dados é mais rápido fazer select campo1,campo2 from ... do que fazer select * from ...

Comment: To ligado. Mas talvez a resposta do amigo te sirva !

Answer (score -1):

Faz assim amigo:

```
query = query.Select(i=> new { Id = i.Id, Nome = i.Nome }).Where(x => x.Nome.ToUpper().Contains(searchString));
```

Comment: Dá para comentar/explicar porque essa solução seria resposta para a pergunta?

Comment: Olá Rafael, não posso fazer assim, pois o nome pode ou não vir, não é obrigatório